# video popup + text

Tags: javascript, video, text, youtube, popup

I am using a script to play my youtube video in a popup window. Is it possible to change this so I can play the video in the popup, but underneath add 5 lines of text as information about the video?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function showPopup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=315,width=560,top=200,left=300,resizable');
    newwindow.focus();
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var win = window.open("", "win", "width=500,height=600"); // a window object
win.document.open("text/html", "replace");
win.document.write('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bKkESJ1abRA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><p>Your text</p><p>Hey, moar text :D</p>');
win.document.close();
win.focus();
```

Try this!

After your request in the comments:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openWindow(url,id){
                var win = window.open("", "win", "width=500,height=600"); // a window object
                var myText = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
                win.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                win.document.write('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="'+url+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+myText);
                win.document.close(); 
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="asd.jpg" onclick="openWindow('http://www.youtube.com/embed/bKkESJ1abRA','div1')">
        <img src="dsa.jpg" onclick="openWindow('http://www.youtube.com/embed/bKkESJ1abRA','div2')">
        <div style="display: none" id="div1">
            <p>My text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="div2">
            <p>My text 2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BRAQD/

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong, cause I'm only getting a fullscreen of my video now :/

Comment: I just tryed it and it works for me. Are you using the same code that i posted?

Comment: No, just use mine. Can you explain exactly what you get? Only a fullscreen of the video without the example text?

Comment: Which browser do you use? I created a Fiddle, does it works for you? http://jsfiddle.net/VSPRf/

Comment: I use safari, is that a problem? in the fiddle I just see the body text Hello!

Comment: Okay, I see the result in chrome, thats what I want, but it's for a portfolio with 8 thumbs, and I need it onClick for each video, each one with another text

Comment: Enclose it in a function, and call it in the onclick event of your thumbs, maybe passing the video url through a parameter and the text throug one/more hidden divs. (if you don't understand, i modify the answer adding it)

Comment: ok thanks, I'm not the javascript pro :p but I'm going to try this (if you can, please :D)